# the store route won't take POST as a method

Tags: php, laravel, form-helpers, bootstrap-form-helper

am working on a simple blog project using Laravel, i was trying to store the data passed by my create post form to my store controller and it won't accept the POST method. even tho whenever i list my routes i see that the store route accept a post method . i used a get method and that worked . until i tried to upload images, it started telling me that the image file must be an image even tho it is an image. i then discovered the image is not being passed by the form in the first place

```
    {{ Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method'=> 'GET', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
        {{Form::text('title' , '' , ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> 'this is a title place holder'])}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('body', 'body')}}
        {{Form::textarea('body' , '' , [ 'id' => 'article-ckeditor' , 'class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> 'body'])}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::file('cover_image')}}
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">

    </div>
    {{Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>"btn btn-info"])}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and this is my controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
        'cover_image' 
    ]);

    //handle file upload

    if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){

        $image = $request->file('cover_image');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('storage/coverimages/' . $filename );
        image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location);

    }
    else{
        echo 'this is shit';
        $filename = 'noimage.jpg';
    }

    //create post
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $post->cover_image = $filename;
    $post->save();

    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Post created');
}
```

Comment: `method'=> 'GET',` well, it's not sending as POST...

Comment: Please show us the routes defined for the controller

Comment: Just a side note: you cannot upload files with a GET method. You have to use POST.

Answer (score 0):

See here

```
Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method'=> 'GET', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'])
```

'method'=>'GET' so your form will be submitted as GET request and not POST.

Answer (score 0):

try this on your form declaraction `'files' => true`

Answer (score 0):

**First**

I noticed you are using

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
```

you don't need to use form method spoofing. Post method already supported in laravel as HTTP request method.
check the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing)

**second**

You are submiting form so don't use get method use Post instead